# Why $$PWD instead of $PWD in TI x-loader makefile for omap devices

Tags: linux, makefile, embedded, gnu

I started to analyse the TI X-Loader, including it's makefiles. I found the following lines in the top makefile:

```
TOPDIR := $(shell if [ "$$PWD" != "" ]; then echo $$PWD; else pwd; fi)
```

and

```
ifeq (include/config.mk,$(wildcard include/config.mk))
...
```

Regarding the first line: i know that "$PWD" means the value of PWD (the working directory)
My question:
why the double dollar sign in this special case?

Regarding the second line: I'm trying to understand what is compared and why. 
I already red the GNU MAKE manual wildcard explanation. I'm still missing something.

My questions:
what is the "$(wildcard" for?
Which config.mk files exactly are compared to each other?
Why are they compared? (this question is more about the makefile structure)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Martin

Comment: 1. Avoid posting multiple queries in the same question.  2. `$$` is used to refer to a _shell_ variable, `$` to refer to a _make_ variable.  3. The `wildcard` line seems redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In make, you escape a dollar sign (so that it's not expanded by make) using two dollar signs (`$$`).  So, if you write `$PWD` then make will interpret the `$P` as a make variable reference, which is likely not set and so empty, and the result (passed to the shell) will be `WD`.  If you use `$$PWD` then the dollar sign is escaped and the result passed to the shell command will be `$PWD` which is what you want.

For the second line, the `wildcard` function will, among other things, expand to the empty string if there are no files that match the wildcard.  So this invocation of `wildcard` is testing to see if the file `include/config.mk` exists or not.  If it does, then the result of the function will be `include/config.mk` and the `ifeq` test will be true.  If it doesn't then the result will be the empty string and the `ifeq` test will be false.

Nothing here is comparing the contents or timestamps or anything else of `include/config.mk`.  This is purely a "does this file exist?" test.